# Read from a file or read the file into a buffer and then use the buffer(in C++)?

Tags: c++, inputstream

I am writing a parser wherein, I need to read characters from a file. But I will be reading the file character by character, and may even stop reading in the middle if come conditions do not satisy.

So is it advisable to create an ifstream of the file, and seek to the position everytime and start reading from there, Or should I read the entire file into a stream or buffer, and then use that instead??

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use a memory-mapped file.

Boost offers a cross-platform one: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

Comment: But I am assuming this might have compatibility issues when used in diff OSs'?

Comment: Sure. So, "if you can". If not, see the other answers :)

Comment: But thanks anyway, since I know it now, I can use it appropriate situations :)

Answer (score 1):

How big is the file? Do you make more than one pass?  Whether you read it into an in-memory buffer or not, reading the file will consume (file size/`BUFSIZ`) reads to go through the whole thing.  Reading character by character doesn't matter, because the underlying read still consumes BUFSIZ bytes at a time (unless you take steps to change that behavior) -- it just hands them out character-by-character.

If you're reading it and processing it in one pass anyway, then reading it into memory will mean you *always* need (file size/`BUFSIZ`) reads, where -- assuming the reason for stopping is distributed equiprobably -- reading it and processing in line will take on average (file size/`BUFSIZ`) * 0.5 reads, which on a big file could be a substantial gain.

An even more important question might be "what are you doing looking for this complicated a solution?"  The amount of time it takes to figure out the cute solution probably dominates any gains you'll make from looking for something fancier than the standard "while not end of file, get character and process" solution.

Comment: The file will not be too big, a text file basically. But the thing is I dont need the entire file at all times, I will start processing from the beginning of the file, parsing each character, and if there is an illegal character I will discard the rest of the file.                                                               It is for this reason that I was looking for an elegant solution which doesnt need the overhead of allocating unnecessary buffer space for the entire file, considering that some part of it may be discarded anyway

Comment: Okay, then the solution is to open an `ifstream` on the file, read it character by character using `ifstream::get`.  The underlying system will worry about buffers and can be pretty well depended upon to be as efficient as possible,

Answer (score 0):

Seeking the position every time and reading wouldn't be a better option for this as it degrades the performance,
**Try creating a Buffer** and read from that that would be a better idea and more efficient

Try to read all the file contents at a stretch to the buffer and then process the subsequent input needs with the buffer and without reading from the file everytime,,

Comment: So you mean a better idea should be to read the file into a buffer first?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I was a little confused because I guess ifstream also buffers the data, and it actually supplies the data from the buffer first, and only if the data is not there does it go back to get more from the file.

Comment: ya,, ifstream works as how you said,, it would read from the file each time,, uses no buffer,,

Comment: If this answer satisfies u,, close the question,,

Answer (score 0):

On a full service OS (i.e. Windows, Mac OS, Linux, BSD...) the operating system will have a caching mechanism that handles this for you to some extent (and assuming your usage patterns meet some definition of "usual").

Unless you are experiencing unacceptable performance you might want to merrily ignore the whole issue (i.e. just use the naive file access primitives).